# how to return string with select box with select option selected as per a given variable

Tags: javascript, php, datatable, datatables, wordpress-plugin-creation

I using Datatable library to show a table in wordpress custom plugin where I need to return selectbox input. The select box option should display the option as it is saved in database but it is showing the first option always.

How to code the same thing in js when the select input is returned for a column in datatable. I have tried the following way:

```
columns: [{
       
{
            'data': null,
            'render': function (data, type, row, meta) {
                 
                
            return '<select class="selectpicker" name="pm" id="pm-' + row.mls + '"><option value="Tafolla">Tafolla</option><option value="Lucy">Lucy</option></select>';

            }
         },
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well first get the JS value that is selected then based off return call the php value in a separate call not inlineHTML  . Try not overcomplicate cross language calls ...

```js
document.getElementById('my-select').addEventListener('change', function() {
  console.log('You selected: ', this.value);

 //Call PHP values based on selection e.g
 if(this.value == 2) 
 {
   var text = " <?php echo ($row['status'] == 'AR')?'selected='selected':''; ?>";

 }


});
```

```html
<select id="my-select">
  <option value="1">One</option>
  <option value="2">Two</option>
  <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

The other way of doing it is in plain php with HTML select

```
<select name="formGender">
   <option value="">Select...</option>
   <option value="M">Male</option>
   <option value="F">Female</option>
 </select>

//PHP
<?php

 if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']) )
  {
   $varGender = $_POST['formGender'];         
  }

?>
```

Comment: I will need to use return select input as string in js as I am using datatable library following their rules like this: return '<select class="selectpicker" name="pm" id="pm-' + row.mls + '"><option value="Tafolla">Tafolla</option><option value="Lucy">Lucy</option></select>';. And the problem is I need to set the option selected as the value I get from database say a given variable pm=Tafolla. by default it is always showing the first option. Like in php I can use if/else inside the select input tag to keep the option selected

Comment: Adjusted the answered for plain php form handling . You see the problem you have is that the form is not submitted . That is why the first value is always selected . Either you have to catch the onChange in Javascript or get the value in php after the submit . but for the value to change an action of submit or onchange has to happen

Comment: Maybe my question is not clearly explained. I cannot use php at all, my code is in js. I am using php part to show as an example that how do we do the same thing with js

Comment: Oh so you want to make the selection box dynamically ?
if you creating it on the HTML fly in the return statement just us <option name="" SELECTED> to make that one default ...

Comment: <select id="cars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" selected>Audi</option>
</select>

Comment: I am showing the form with values from db, the form is to edit the values of databse so it will display with values that are already saved. For example if the car value saved in db is volvo then select option "volvo" should remain selected. If car value from db is "audi" then "audi" option of select box will remain selected on page load